# Pass a VBscript function as an argument to the jQuery click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, vbscript

I am authoring a number of HTML files that will be rendered by an IE control embedded in a third-party application.

In order to provide some fairly complex UI elements with the least amount of fuss, I elected to do most of my coding in JavaScript with jQuery. This generally works well, however the host application provides a large library of support functions I will need to call in order to trigger certain actions (such as printing and database updates). These support functions are all in external VBScript (`.vbs`) files that I can include in the HTML files' header.

Calling the VBscript functions and accessing global variables from within my JavaScript functions works flawlessly when done directly, but I can't figure out how to pass a reference to a function that was defined in VBScript to a jQuery event handler.

For example, the following code:

```
 1: <script type="text/vbscript">
 2:   Function handleClick
 3:      MsgBox "Clicked."
 4:   End Function
 5: </script>
 6:
 7: <script type="text/javascript">
 8:   $(function () {
 9:      $("#clickableThing1").click(handleClick);
10:   });
11: </script>
```

...generates the following error on line 9:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Replacing line 9 with the following, however, works as desired:

```
$("#clickableThing1").click(function() {
   handleClick();
});
```

I've tried passing `handleClick` to `click()` as both `document.handleClick` and as `this.handleClick` to no avail.

While I can certainly continue to wrap the VBScript calls in anonymous JavaScript functions, that seems unnecessarily verbose as, *surely* those functions must be defined in the DOM *somewhere*, right?

Can anyone tell me how I can refer to those VBScript functions directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can. I think if you try, the VBScript function is just going to get evaluated in place and its return value will be passed into `click()`.

I'll offer another solution, though it may not meet your requirements. You can use the jQuery `attr()` function to assign an inline handler to the DOM element.

In my experience, when using VBScript functions as event handlers, you need to specify them using parens *or* include a `language="vbscript"` attribute on the DOM element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    // This should work (using parens)...
    $("#clickableThing1").attr("onclick", "handleClick()");

    // or, so should this (no parens on function call)...
    $("#clickableThing1").attr("language", "vbscript").attr("onclick", "handleClick");
});
</script>
```